# Arquillian remote integration tests AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, jboss-arquillian

I want to run some integration tests when building so I've configured arquillian.xml as:

```
<container qualifier="widlfly-remote" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="managementAddress">88.88.88.88</property>
        <property name="managementPort">9990</property>
        <property name="username">blabla</property>
        <property name="password">blabla</property>
        <property name="host">88.88.88.88</property>
        <property name="port">8080</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

I have good degree of automation so I don't know the exact IP of the instances I'm deploying to. 
Arquillian Docs are not clear about what I can do.
I'm expecting to do something like:

```
<container qualifier="widlfly-remote" default="true">
<configuration>
    <property name="managementAddress">${envOrWhateverProp}</property>
    <property name="managementPort">${envOrWhateverProp}</property>
    <property name="username">${envOrWhateverProp}</property>
    <property name="password">${envOrWhateverProp}</property>
    <property name="host">${envOrWhateverProp}</property>
    <property name="port">${envOrWhateverProp}</property>
</configuration>
```

Whatever it can be environment variable or Maven flag (-DmyPropHere ).
I need some way to fill up those from outside and keeping code unique across all versions.

Any help?

Comment: Yes this is supported, and in near future custom ways will be provided, but for now look this javadoc https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/blob/master/config/impl-base/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/config/impl/extension/StringPropertyReplacer.java#L98 which describes the current behaviour.

Comment: Yes I ended up using within Maven as -DenvOrWhateverProp=value